# i can't move an uploaded image to a spesific directory

Tags: php, image, upload, move

This is my code :

```
<?php
session_start();

include "connect.php";
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$teks= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['teks']);
$photo= $_POST['photo'];

$path_file = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$type_file   = $_FILES['photo']['type'];
$name_file   = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$directory   = "image/$nama_file";

if (!empty($lokasi_file)) {
  move_uploaded_file($lokasi_file,$direktori); }
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT username from member where username='$username'");

  $result=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

  mysql_query("Insert into posting (username, pic_post, text_post, location, datetime)  values('$username','$photo','$teks', '$photo', NOW())");

  header("Location: member.php");
}
?>
```

I've got an issue with this code, and can't move the uploaded image into the `/image`  folder.

Comment: Misspelling between `$name_file` and `$nama_file`.  Always enable PHP's error reporting when developing code, as it would complain about an undefined variable. At the top of your code: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Please post your HTML form as well.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written is full of bugs

$photo= $_POST['photo']; This is wrong... $photo= $_FILES['photo'];

Please go through the bellow Link, you will find a good tutorial here.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

**New Edit :** ( I have Just edited the your code)

```
<?php
session_start();

include "connect.php";
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$teks= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['teks']);

$photo= $_FILES['photo']['name'];

$path_file = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$type_file   = $_FILES['photo']['type'];
$name_file   = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$directory   = "image/$nama_file";

$target_file = $directory . basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);

if (!empty($lokasi_file)) {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file); 
 }
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT username from member where username='$username'");

  $result=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

  mysql_query("Insert into posting (username, pic_post, text_post, location, datetime)  values('$username','$photo','$teks', '$photo', NOW())");

  header("Location: member.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: `$_FILES['photo']` will hold an array, so the variable `$photo` won't be of much use later in the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: In insert statement you have to use it in your way. For example I am inserting the file name, then this should be $photo= $_FILES['photo']['name'];

Answer (score 0):

You have several erros in your code.
Check this block

```
$photo= $_POST['photo'];
$path_file = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$type_file   = $_FILES['photo']['type'];
$name_file   = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$directory   = "image/$nama_file";
```

- Files are in `$_FILES` array, not in `$_POST`, so your photo will be `$photo= $_FILES['photo'];`
- You never use `$path_file`, so why is it?
- You have a type, with `$nama_file`, that is `$name_file`
- Where is `$lokasi_file` and `$direktori` come from? That should be `$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']` in move upload.
- Do not use mysql functions, they are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.
- Escape your variables comes from outside, because of sql injection, or use prepared statements.
- You do not use the result of your first `$sql`.
- You can not store `$photo` in your database, because that is an array
- Add `exit;` or `die;` after redirection.
- Sidenote: Why are you store the location of the file twice?

So your final code will be something like this, but again, change the `mysql_` functions!

```
session_start();
include "connect.php";
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $teks = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['teks']);
    $type_file = $_FILES['photo']['type'];
    $name_file = "image/" . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]['tmp_name'], $name_file)) {
        //Why is it here, for what? Never used the $res (what is acually $row)
        //$sql = mysql_query("SELECT username from member where username='" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'");
        //$res = mysql_query($sql);
        mysql_query("Insert into posting (username, pic_post, text_post, location, datetime)  "
            . "values('" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "',"
            . " '" . mysql_real_escape_string($name_file) . "',"
            . " '" . $teks . "',"
            . " '" . mysql_real_escape_string($name_file) . "', NOW())");
        header("Location: member.php");
        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks so much for answer.. 
and here is my successfully code :

```
<?php
session_start();

include "connect.php";
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$koneksi = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($koneksi, "dbjashik");
$teks = $_POST['teks'];
$folder = "image";
$tmp_name = $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"];
$name = $folder."/".$_FILES["photo"]["name"];

//to moving the file into /image directory
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $name);

//inserting query
$input = mysqli_query($koneksi, "INSERT INTO posting VALUES(null, '$username', '$name' ,'$teks', '$name', NOW() )");


  header("Location: member.php");
}

?>
```